# How to add onchange event in sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE?

Tags: php, tinymce, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I need to detect if tinymce content has changed. I am using symfony 1.4, sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE.

Part of my form has the following code:

```
$tiny_mce_config =  'theme: "advanced",' . 
        'theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,link",' .
        'theme_advanced_buttons2: "",' .
        'theme_advanced_buttons3: "",' .
        'theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "none",'.
        'cleanup: true,'.
        'force_br_newlines: true,'.
        'force_p_newlines: false,'.
        'forced_root_block: "",'.
        'valid_elements : "br,strong,b,em,i,a[href|title|target]"';


$this->setWidgets(array(
'intro'  => new sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE(
    array(
       'width'  => '616',
       'config'     => $tiny_mce_config
    )
)
));
```

Rendering in my template, I did this:

```
<?php echo $form['intro']->renderLabel('Introduction'); ?>
<?php echo $form['intro']->render(array('rows' => 3, 'cols' => 100)); ?>
<?php echo $form['intro']->renderError(); ?>
```

I tried putting onchange event to the original textarea, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a jQuery selector as @MichalTrojanowski says is the best way I think. It's unobstructive.

You can also give the attribute from the `->render()` method, as you did for `cols` & `rows`:

```
<?php echo $form['intro']->render(array(
    'rows'     => 3, 
    'cols'     => 100, 
    'onchange' => 'myfunction();'
 )); ?>
```

By the way, I don't think this method will be fired when user will edit content. Since TinyMCE re-create an iframe (or sort of) to handle the editor.

You might better have a look at the onChange event built inside TinyMCE. Something like these :

- [TinyMCE onchange documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onChange)
- [TinyMCE onchange_callback documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aonchange_callback)

Comment: I tried your first solution but it did not work. However, I accepted your answer for your point that suggested method will not work when user will edit content; since, TinyMCE re-create an iframe to handle the editor. Btw, thank you for the links.

Answer (score 1):

You can either try to pass onchange function in the `attributes` array of the Widget:

```
new sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE(array(...), array('onchange' => '...'));
```

Or give the widget a specific id or class and use jQuery to add the behavior.

```
$('#myTinyMCETextarea').change(function() {...});
```

I would go for the latter option.

Comment: I tried the mentioned ways but still, even if I edit the rendered widget, onchange event is not fired.